# Копирование строки в TextBox через связывание данных (Data Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В коде XAML объявлен TextBox. В коде программы объявлена строка mystring. Как сделать так, чтобы при любом изменении строки при помощи binding содержимое строки автоматически копировалось в TextBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеем код

```
partial class WindowX : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public WindowX()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _something;

    public string Something
    {
        get
        {
            return _something;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _something)
            {
                _something = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Something");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Имеем разметку

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Something}" />
```

Контекст данных для XAML установлен на WindowX.

Answer (score -1):

к сожалению не Binding, а велосипед:

```
public class ObservableObject<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get{return _value;}
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            RaiseValueChanged();
        }
    }

    public delegate void EventDelegate(T EventArg);

    public event EventDelegate ValueChanged;

    protected virtual void RaiseValueChanged()
    {
        if (ValueChanged != null)
            ValueChanged(_value);
    }

    public ObservableObject(T value = default(T))
    {       
        _value = value;
    }
}

ObservableObject<string> a = new ObservableObject<string>();
a.ValueChanged += value => TextBox1.Text = value;
a.Value = "A";
a.Value = "B";
a.Value = "C";
```